# Does the Director's Cut of "Clive Barker's The Plague" explain anything about why the children were afflicted?

Tags: clive-barker, the-plague

So, my wife and I watched *Clive Barker's The Plague* and we're both a bit baffled. The basic premise of the film is that one day, every child younger than nine suddenly goes comatose, having a seizure twice a day, one of which is precisely at 10 PM. Then, the film cuts to ten years later where the children all suddenly wake up and apparently go on a murder spree. Sometimes they kill people and sometimes they do some sort of thing where they put their hands on a person's face and snap their neck, with an implication in the plot that they took the person's soul. It's really rather muddled.

I've read online that [the film is not based on Clive Barker's stories and he was not involved in the filming](http://rheaven.blogspot.com/2008/09/clive-barkers-plague.html), but that his company was involved in recutting the film to be something other than what was originally intended, something that the director claims was much to its detriment. He apparently has his own cut of the film, which he is legally unable to release, but I know that people on the Internet have a talent for unearthing footage that's not legally available. Has anyone commented on what the difference are, and whether that cut better explains what happened to the children, why they woke up, and why they're doing what they're doing?

Comment: Might be worth linking to http://www.spreadingtheplague.com but unfortunately it looks like the campaign to get Screen Gems (the movie's distributor) to release the director's cut wasn't successful

Comment: I was unaware of that page and campaign. That may give people somewhere to look for answers, maybe reaching out to the director.