# Movie that starts with a news broadcast about a virus which only infects nine-year-olds

Tags: story-identification, movie, virus

The film starts with the said news broadcast, then pans out to show every child around beginning to convulse and foam at the mouth. The only other part I remember is that it cuts to the aftermath and a high school. The kids are always in bed, but at a certain hour, they began to convulse and shake, and nurses would strap them to the bed, and there was a part where a nurse barely managed to strap him down.

Comment: In roughly which year did you watch this movie, and when do you think it was made? Also, which country and language did you watch it in?

Comment: I watched it around 2016-17, but it looked like it was the late 70s to mid-80s. my dad liked watching them on amazon prime or something like it.

Comment: Were you able to determine whether the film was *The Plague*?

Comment: :) Just checking the once more, since I saw you'd posted recently.

Answer (score 13):

This is *[Clive Barker's The Plague](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Plague_(2006_film))* from 2006.

> In 1983, simultaneously one day all of the world's children under the age of nine fall into a catatonic state. For the next ten years, every child who is born, is born in a state of catatonia. During this state, the children experience seizures twice a day and seem to develop superhuman strength. In 1993, all the children wake up, hell-bent on killing all adults. Things get even worse when the adults realize the children have a sort of collective brain—what one learns, they all learn. The children get smarter by the hour. First they disable the engines in almost every car and then set up roadblocks to stop the adults from escaping. Then they learn how to use firearms. The children also take the souls of the ones they kill as a part of deliverance. The adults must find a way to stop them before it's too late.

### The Trailer

Not a bad film, but it's worth noting that [Clive Barker had very little to do with the film and the Director claims that it was recut in a way that completely changed it](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/170786/does-the-directors-cut-of-clive-barkers-the-plague-explain-anything-about-wh).